# How to handle ranged features in data preparation

Tags: python

I have some string features which is format is ranged number, how do i deal with it?

```
df.Age
Out[6]: 
0      30-44
1      18-29
2      30-44
3      30-44
4      30-44
```

Comment: What do you mean by `handle`? What do you want to do with it? Maybe you want to treat it as [categrorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html)?

Comment: i don't know what i want to do with it, i thought if it's a number values but the type is string then we should convert it to numerical type to make it as a good properly type feature(please correct me if i'm wrong)? will it still give us good feature although we treat it (string that is a ranged number) as categorical data by encoding it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```py
numbers = [int(num) for num in data.replace(' ', '-').split('')]
```